# Postgresql query to select most recent coming date time

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I have a 2 tables subject_master and slot_master, one subject have multiple slots, I want to run a query that should ruturns the most coming slot , it should retunr the distinct values only
e.g . I have following 2 tables

Table1 : subject_master

| subject_id | subject_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UHGAwlfrGDFwU | Maths | active |
| X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | Physics | active |
| Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | Chemistry | active |

Table 2 : slot_master

| slot_id | subject_id | date | start_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aMkJaKeTMSqRt | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 02-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| Njpm1BJknxaHb | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 04-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| XwE8fGvFp8ofI | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 06-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| J0FnzWAcdNBIb | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 09-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| 7jKgQM9Ly7xB1 | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 11-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| LaQD4KMgrNfQp | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 13-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| jOB2zXHhUvzUZ | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 16-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| wQ8anzVi649H2 | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 18-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| 8koqL52n1rNWX | Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | 20-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| 5HOMvEBusoSGO | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 01-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| Nm437BpC2oOoW | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 03-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| VOs9BTmA4j1ar | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 05-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| 1DCSINyTS80aD | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 08-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| ihl0sv0RANvbs | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 10-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| mbAg9pr9PopNW | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 12-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| VUVJlWCbgo30h | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 15-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| LAW8p1XTe2GzW | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 17-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| l9JweYVRhrKiH | X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | 19-08-2022 | 09:00 |
| 4rhxtLpBIgk60 | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 13-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| 7PYANuy3cfI9b | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 04-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| ariHVdxwq9Qlq | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 11-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| eoabdysdnEhgo | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 06-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| l6CPBB8GHVdMz | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 09-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| nMzwARCSb4gun | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 02-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| RotO7tJeYGUks | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 16-08-2022 | 06:00 |
| UXaDInLqulUGp | UHGAwlfrGDFwU | 18-08-2022 | 06:00 |

I want a query that return the expected outoput
if current date is 30-07-2022 and Current time is 05:00

| subject_id | subject_name | start_time | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UHGAwlfrGDFwU | Maths | 06:30 | 02-08-2022 |
| X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | Physics | 09:00 | 01-08-2022 |
| Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | Chemistry | 06:00 | 01-08-2022 |

I am not good in explaning, I am just trying to fetch the most recent coming slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and an `INNER JOIN`

> ```
> WITH CTE As (SELECT 
>       "subject_id"
>       , "date"
>       , "start_time"
>       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "subject_id" ORDER BY  "date", "start_time") rn
> FROM slot_master 
> WHERE DATE("date") + "start_time"::time  > DATE('2022-07-3') + '05:00'::time)
> SELECT       CTE."subject_id"
> ,subject_name
>       , "date"
>       , "start_time" FROM CTE  INNER JOIN  subject_master ON cTE.subject_id = subject_master.subject_id
> WHERE subject_master.status = 'active' AND rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> subject_id    | subject_name | date       | start_time
> :------------ | :----------- | :--------- | :---------
> UHGAwlfrGDFwU | Maths        | 02-08-2022 | 06:00     
> X3Sv7nE5HqhXg | Physics      | 01-08-2022 | 09:00     
> Y7fHY4mEJmHaS | Chemistry    | 02-08-2022 | 06:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dfdbe350b7d4600d670cc253afa4aa3d)*

Comment: This exactily I was looking for , thank you so much you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, you can use `select distinct on` to accomplish this.  So long as the `date` is of type `date` and `start_time` is of type `time`, this will work:

```
select distinct on (s.subject_id) s.subject_id, s.subject_name, slot.date, slot.start_time
  from subject_master s
       join slot_master slot
         on slot.subject_id = s.subject_id
 where slot.date + slot.start_time >= '2022-07-30 05:00'
 order by s.subject_id, slot.date, slot.start_time;
```